# Playsound TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, playsound

I can't get playsound to work, it instead gives me `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`. Please bear with me here, I'm a first timer here and not very good with python.

The error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
  File "C:\Users\memer\Desktop\Internecion\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    playsound(r'C:/Users/memer/Desktop/Internecion/ICONTHEME.mp3')
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Dunno why I'm getting this. Tried all three of these, none worked. All net the same error.

```py
from playsound import playsound
playsound('C:\\Users\\memer\\Desktop\\Internecion\\ICONTHEME.mp3')
```

```py
from playsound import playsound
playsound(r'C:\Users\memer\Desktop\Internecion\ICONTHEME.mp3')
```

```py
from playsound import playsound
playsound(r'C:/Users/memer/Desktop/Internecion/ICONTHEME.mp3')
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\memer\Desktop\Internecion\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    playsound(r'C:\Users\memer\Desktop\Internecion\ICONTHEME.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\memer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\playsound.py", line 34, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\memer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\playsound.py", line 27, in winCommand
    exceptionMessage = ('\n    Error ' + str(errorCode) + ' for command:'
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Comment: Full traceback, please

Comment: Sorry, it's added now.

Comment: Format it properly (as a code block), it's unreadable ATM

Comment: Looks like there is missing a ```)``` at the end

Comment: @flappix: no, that's a line in the `playsound` library that wraps to another line.

Comment: This is probably more of a bug in `playsound` than in your code. Looking at the code of this package I couldn't find an obvious way to reproduce the error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the line numbers, this appears to be an **old version** of the package (perhaps [this one](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/blob/b7849a3d559fd8b39749f7dcc5c5bcf07c866728/playsound.py)) which targeted Python 2 and (as was common for that version) did not handle character and byte strings in a consistent fashion.